How to Make a Gradient Background Responsive and Prevent Clipping Issues?


body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #121212;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.card {
  background: linear-gradient(145deg, #1e1e1e, #292929);
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-align: center;

  .title {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;

    .highlight {
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff9a9e, #fad0c4);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }
  }

  .description {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 15px 0;
    line-height: 1.6;
  }

  .offer {
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #00acee;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .button {
    background: #00acee;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: background 0.3s ease;

    &:hover {
      background: #007bb5;
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .card {
    padding: 15px;

    .title {
      font-size: 1.5rem;
    }

    .description {
      font-size: 0.9rem;
    }

    .offer {
      font-size: 0.9rem;
    }

    .button {
      padding: 8px 16px;
    }
  }
}
<div class="card">
  <h1 class="title">Carnival for <span class="highlight">Home Internet</span></h1>
  <p class="description">
    Experience the finest home internet with nation's largest and #1 fiber broadband. 
    From streaming to working from home, and gaming to video calls, Carnival delivers the 
    fastest and most reliable service.
  </p>
  <p class="offer">★ Up to 100 Mbps Unlimited Internet Package</p>
  <a href="#" class="button">Find out more here</a>
</div>



I am working on a component that has a gradient background. However, I am encountering several issues with how the gradient renders. The main problems are as follows:
The gradient background sometimes gets clipped or doesn't fully cover the intended area of the component.
On devices with smaller screens or when the size of the component dynamically changes, the gradient either looks distorted or does not align properly with the content.
I am struggling to make the gradient background responsive so that it scales correctly while maintaining its visual quality and proportions across all screen sizes.
Additionally, I am concerned about ensuring cross-browser compatibility to avoid any unexpected behavior in different browsers.

